# Jersey Jackson and codehaus vs. fasterxml

Tags: jersey, jackson

I'm using Jersey 1.17.1 with Jackson 2.2.1.

It seems like Jackson switched packages from `org.codehaus` to `com.fasterxml`. I have all my code configured properly and using the latest jackson. However, it seems like Jersey is still pulling in `org.codehaus.jackson`. Is there any way to mitigate this or should I stick with the `codehaus` packages until jersey is upgraded to use the `fasterxml` packages?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The older Jackson libraries are being pulled in as dependencies of the [jersey-json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json/1.17) artifact. When

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
```

is included in your POM you will automatically get versions of the org.codehaus.jackson libraries included in your project. Unfortunately, jersey-json itself has link time dependencies on the Jackson classes, so you can't simply use [exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html). What you want do to instead is omit it entirely. It's really a kind of wrapper library around a bunch of JSON libraries that you do not necessarily need. Once removed, you can add dependencies for the Jackson 2.2.1 libraries and JAX-RS provider:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that with jersey-json removed you no longer have a Stax2, Jettison, or JAXB provider. If you need those then you will have to locate and add dependencies for them manually.

Comment: Starting from Jackson 2.2, the  code location is https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/json/pom.xml.