# org.codehaus.jackson versus com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Tags: java, json, jackson

Are `org.codehaus.jackson` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` related?
I have

> org.codehaus.jackson  jackson-all version 1.7.2

and

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core > jackson-databind version 2.4.3

in my `pom.xml`.
I am not sure if they are redundant and can conflict.

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey Jackson and codehaus vs. fasterxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876482/jersey-jackson-and-codehaus-vs-fasterxml)

Answer (score 255):

`org.codehaus.jackson` is an older version of Jackson.

`com.fasterxml.jackson` represents the new project and package.

The reason is, Jackson has moved from Codehaus to Github when releasing Jackson 2.

See [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation-Jackson-2.0) for details.

I would recommend removing `org.codehaus.jackson` references from your POM, re-building and looking for errors (not likely but possible).

If you find any, you can adapt the code using deprecated API to the newer Jackson version's API.

Comment: also fix the old *codehaus* *ObjectNode* *"put"* method by changing it to *"putPOJO"* when using new *fasterxml* package, which is deprecated in new *fasterxml* jackson package.

Comment: Also don't mix annotation from one library and ObjectMapper from other, we had many bugs because of this mix.