# Not able to send JSON object from Spring controller using Java

Tags: java, json, spring

I am returning a simple list object using spring controller. I have annotated correct with @ResponseBody to my method, but still its not able to convert from arraylist. I have added jackson-mapper-asl jar too.

My code of controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/service/greeting")
public class SpringServiceController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getCustomers() {
        EmployeeServiceImpl c = new EmployeeServiceImpl();
        return c.getCustomers();
    }
}
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.biq.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:187)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What exactly im missing?

Comment: what do you actually get then?

Comment: Use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

Comment: Maybee, ObjectMapper is not present as Spring Bean? I wonder about logs you have now. Could you provide it?

Comment: @oleg.cherednik, sorry for not putting logs. I have updated now with log. Please check

Comment: @Andremoniy, I tested with both

Comment: @MárioFernandes, please check log. I have updated

Comment: Yes. It seems so. Please check that you have e.g. Jackson in dependencies and ObjectMapper is available as Spring bean. List object could be mapped with default serializer, so you do not have to write custom one.

Comment: have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the latest json 2 jar. Refer this for difference between the old Json and new json 2 lib [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782706/org-codehaus-jackson-versus-com-fasterxml-jackson-core)
Have below jars in your classpath:

1. jackson-annotations-2.7.5.jar
2. jackson-core-2.7.5.jar
3. jackson-databind-2.7.5.jar

version can be different one. it should solve your issue.
If you are using maven, then

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency will transitively add the abovelibraries to the classpath.

Comment: Excellent Sangam. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try using @RestController instead @Controller.

Rest Controller annotation implicitly converts http response object into json/xml.

Comment: Register an object mapper class . Annotate this with @component and scan that package as well. Spring will automatically create the bean out of this and will use it .

Answer (score 0):

Register an object mapper class . Annotate this with @component and scan that package as well. Spring will automatically create the bean out of this and will use it .

```
@Component
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomObjectMapper.class);

public CustomObjectMapper() {
    super();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
    this.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
}
}
```