# Deseralize JSON with Jackson into a list of heterogeneous elements

Tags: java, json, data-structures, jackson

In my JSON I have an element with the following contents:

```
{
    ...
    "locations": [
        [
            {
                "location_type": "permanent",
                "position": "at",
                "accuracy": "exact"
            },
            "and",
            {
                "location_type": "permanent",
                "position": "in",
                "accuracy": "exact"
            }
        ],
        "or",
        {
            "location_type": "temporary",
            "position": "at",
            "accuracy": "exact"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

As shown, an element of `locations` can be:

- a location
- a logical operator
- a list of locations (allowing for complex locations)

I'm getting "Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.processor.transformation.json.Location` out of START_ARRAY token".

**How can I consume this into a data structure using Jackson?**

What I tried so far:

1. Providing a `Location(String logicalOperator)` constructor helps for a flat list case. (I basically turn the operator into a special value of `Location`.)
2. Adding a `Location(List<Location> subLocations)` or a `Location(Location[] subLocations)` constructor doesn't help for this case.

Note: I am not in control of the JSON format so I cannot encode it in a more Jackson-friendly way.

Comment: You're going to need a custom de-serializer for that. You can't just add a constructor.

Comment: @saifahmad Please review duplicate status. This is a different problem, with a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a custom de-serializer for that. You can't just add a constructor.

Here's a self-contained example with class `Foo`, that can be either represented by its own property `"foo" : "someString"` or by some logical operator `"and"` or `"or"`, etc. as a `String` literal, intended to represent a `Foo` instance whose `foo` property will be the value of that literal.

This may or may not fit your case exactly, but you can adjust.

In other words:

- `{"foo": "a"}` --> `new Foo("a")`
- `"or"` --> `new Foo("or")`

**Example**

```
// given...

@JsonDeserialize(using=MyDeserializer.class)
class Foo {
    String foo;
    public void setFoo(String s) {
        foo = s;
    }
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public Foo(String s) {
        setFoo(s);
    }
}
```

// and custom de-serializer...

```
class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Foo> {

    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ct)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
        // this JSON object has a "foo" property, de-serialize 
        // injecting its value in Foo's constructor
        if (node.has("foo")) {
            return new Foo(node.get("foo").asText());
        }
        // other case, assuming literal (e.g. "and", "or", etc.)
        // inject actual node as String value into Foo's constructor
        else {
            return new Foo(node.asText());
        }
    }

}

// here's a quick example

String json = "[{\"foo\": \"a\"}, \"or\", {\"foo\": \"b\"}]";
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
List<Foo> list = om.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Foo>>(){});
list.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.foo));
```

**Output**

```
a
or
b
```

**Note** for clarity

This represents a very simple example. 
In your case, you're probably going to want a polymorphic collection of `Location` POJOs mixed with `LogicalOperator` POJOs (or something similar), sharing a common marker interface. 
You can then decide what object to de-serialize based on whether the JSON node features contents (i.e. a location) or the JSON node *is* its contents (e.g. the logical operators).

Comment: While this isn't the final solution I think you pointed me in the right direction. I tried applying `@JsonDeserialize` in various places with `Location` being an interface but that doesn't seem to even trigger the custom deserializer.

Comment: @AdSR what do you mean by "in various places"? You only need to annotate before the class/interface declaration. If you have a common interface for your locations and logical operators, you can annotate before that interface's declaration.

Comment: Never mind, I was trying to use the wrong Jackson package and it didn't match the parser (`org.codehaus...` vs. `com.fasterxml...`). In the end the only difference between your solution and mine is that I dispatch on node type by `node.isArray()` etc.

Comment: @AdSR a**HA**. Yes, the `org.codehaus` is pretty old now - reminds me of my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782706/org-codehaus-jackson-versus-com-fasterxml-jackson-core/30782762#30782762) :D You have plenty of options in your own de-serializer, in the end it boils down to which ever you find handier to deal with your full payload.