# Is it a good practice to add redundant @JsonProperty when using JacksonMapper

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Is it a good practice to add redundant `@JsonProperty` when using `JacksonMapper`? Even if the class vars are same named as the incoming json(and you `deserialize` the `json`)?

- What can be possible upsides?
- What can be possible downsides?

Answer (score 0):

The downside,as you suggested, it's reduandant,especially when this class was [replaced](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/package-summary.html) from codehaus package to [fasterxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782706/org-codehaus-jackson-versus-com-fasterxml-jackson-core) so if you have old property you will have to refactor class

> org.codehaus.jackson is an older version of Jackson.
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson represents the new project and package.