# Java JsonProperty annotation not working when marshalling

Tags: java, json, jackson, marshalling

I have the following POJO (within constructors etc..):

```
public  class GlobalData  implements Serializable {

//constructors getters and setters

    @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty("size-guide")   
    private List<SizeGuide> sizeGuides;

}
```

With the attribute sizeGuide marked with JsonProperty , so when I marshall this using ObjectMapper , the attribute will appear in the JSON named size-guide instead of sizeGuide.

HOWEVER , this is not working , when I do the ObjectMapper.write value as String method , the attribute doesn't "change" his name , it still appear as sizeGuide.

Any hint?

Comment: You appear to be using the Jackson 1 annotation.

Comment: So what sould I do?

Comment: Remove the mixed Jackson 1 and Jackson 2 modules from your project, however you have it configured.

Comment: See [org.codehaus.jackson versus com.fasterxml.jackson.core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782706/org-codehaus-jackson-versus-com-fasterxml-jackson-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```java
public  class GlobalData  implements Serializable {

//constructors getters and setters

    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty("size-guide")   
    private List<SizeGuide> sizeGuides;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to annotate the getter for `getSizeGuides` as per above - for me variable annotation sometimes doesn't work as getter seem to get precedence when (un)marshalling JSON. 
Some explanation and examples are here: http://www.javabyexamples.com/how-to-change-property-name-with-jackson/