# How globally ignore Null Fields with restesy response?

Tags: java, jboss, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

I use JBoss EAP 7.1 with JAVA EE. I can exclude null fields in response using  `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation under class all filed.
Does exist way to exclude globally (in all project) null values in all objects that resteasy return in response, for example here :

```
Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(objet).build()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure `ObjectMapper` instance in your app:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

See also:

- [JBoss resteasy - Custom Jackson provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838240/jboss-resteasy-custom-jackson-provider)
- [Resteasy jboss7 jackson configuration](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/174506)

Comment: Is it possible to do that in Java EE application? I don't have spring there. And without adding new jars. ResteasyJacksonProvider is not found.

Comment: `Spring` is not required there. Second link shows how to do it. Also take a look on [Custom ObjectMapper with Jersey 2.2 and Jackson 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872931/custom-objectmapper-with-jersey-2-2-and-jackson-2-1), [Jersey Jackson and codehaus vs. fasterxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876482/jersey-jackson-and-codehaus-vs-fasterxml), [Jersey 2.6 Jackson provider registering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935273/jersey-2-6-jackson-provider-registering)